# Sample Fuel request compilation errors

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, fuel

I intent to use the Fuel library inside an Android project.

I added the following to my Gradle file:

```
//core
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.1.0'
//packages
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-json:2.1.0'
```

It was succesfully resolved.

I *copied* the [quick start](https://fuel.gitbook.io/documentation/#quick-start) code to a class, and when I try to compile, I get the following:

[image]

What else is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are importing:

```
import com.github.kittinunf.result.Result
```

Otherwise it tries to use Kotlin's `Result` [class](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html).

Comment: Yes, that was the required step. Shouldn't it be mentioned in the ***official documentation***?